# jquery - appending when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have some radio buttons.

```
<div class="user">
        <input type="radio" class="user-radio" name="user" value="user"/>
        <p>BLABLA</p>
</div>
<div class="user">
        <input type="radio" class="user-radio" name="user" value="user"/>
        <p>BLABLA</p>
</div>
<div class="user">
        <input type="radio" class="user-radio" name="user" value="user"/>
        <p>BLABLA</p>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is, appending the `<div class="user">` with an `<a><a/>` when the radio button inside that div is checked. And when i choose another radio button, I want to remove the last inserted `<a><a/>` and insert a new one to the newly selected radio button's parent div.

I've tried something like this but I couldn't get it to work:

```
<script>
$('.user').click(function () {
    if (!$(".user-radio").is(':checked')) {
        $(this).append('<a></a>');
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnxnk/2/)

```
$('.user-radio').change(function () {
    $('.user a').remove();
    $('.user-radio:checked').parent().append('<a>hello</a>');
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to `show` and `hide` instead of `append` and `remove` elements all time.
And use `change` instead.

**html**

```
<div class="user">
        <input type="radio" class="user-radio" name="user" value="user"/>
        <p>BLABLA</p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">blabla</a>        
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('.user').change(function () {
    $("a").hide();
    $("a", this).show();
});
```

**css**

```
.user a {
    display: none;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/5qn6s/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$('.user-radio').click(function () {
    $('.user > a:last-child').remove()
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().append('<a>test</a>');
    }
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7eRz/

Answer (score 1):

Here i have done complete bins. Demo link as below:

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp93

**HTML:**

```
<div class="user">
  <input type="radio" class="user-radio" name="user" value="user" />
  <p>
    BLABLA
  </p>
</div>
<div class="user">
  <input type="radio" class="user-radio" name="user" value="user"/>
  <p>
    BLABLA
  </p>
</div>
<div class="user">
  <input type="radio" class="user-radio" name="user" value="user"/>
  <p>
    BLABLA
  </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.user p{
  display:inline-block;
  marign:0px;

  padding:0px;
}
input{
  padding:0px;
}
.user{
  border:1px solid #f53322;
  color:#333;
  background:#a3f7a2;
}
.user a{
  color:#112288;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.user-radio').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.user a').remove();
            $('.user-radio:checked').parent(".user").append("<a href='javascript:void(0);'>Add New Link</a>");
            //Another Alternate way is
            /*  $('.user-radio:checked').closest(".user").append("<a href='javascript:void(0);'>Add New Link</a>"); */
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp93

Answer (score 0):

remove the **!** operator and change the first selector from ".user" **.user-radio** and then append the `<a>link</a>` to the parent of **$(this)** element:

```
$('.user-radio').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".user a").remove();
        $(this).parent().append('<a>dwd</a>');
    }
});
```